# multiple if is not checking conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check multiple conditions in my program, but for some reasons it's not working. Here is my code:

```
def removingStrawsComputer():
    removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    global strawsNumber
    if strawsNumber==3:
       removedNumber=random.randint(1,2)
       if strawsNumber==2:
          removedNumber==1
    strawsNumber-=removedNumber 
    return strawsNumber
```

When executing my code, even when strawsNumber = 3, random.randint sometimes select 3.. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Any help would be very appreciated.. :)

Edit:
this my entire code, it is a NIM game. With multiple if's I am trying to avoid that if remaining straws are 3, computer selects 3 and lose right away..

```
player1=raw_input("Iveskite savo varda: ")
player2="Kompiuteris"
howMany=0
gameover=False
strawsNumber=random.randint(10,20)


def removingStrawsComputer():
    removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    global strawsNumber
    if strawsNumber==3:
       removedNumber=random.randint(1,2)
    if strawsNumber==2:
       removedNumber==1
    strawsNumber-=removedNumber 
    return strawsNumber

def removingStrawsHuman():
    global strawsNumber
    strawsNumber-=howMany
    return strawsNumber

def humanLegalMove():
    global howMany
    legalMove=False
    while not legalMove:
        print("Ejima atlieka ",player1)
        howMany=int(input("Kiek objektu nori paimti?(nuo 1 iki 3) ")) 
        if  howMany>3 or howMany<1:
            print("Iveskite skaiciu nuo 1 iki 3")
        else:
            legalMove=True
    while howMany>strawsNumber:
        print("Ivestas skaicius didesnis nei liko objektu")
        howMany=int(input("Kiek objektu nori paimti?(nuo 1 iki 3) "))
    return howMany

def checkWinner(player):
    if strawsNumber==0:
        print(player," laimejo.")
        global gameover
        gameover=True
        return gameover

def resetGameover():
    global gameover
    gameover=False
    return gameover

def game():
    global strawsNumber
    strawsNumber=random.randint(10,20)
    print("Objektu skaicius ",strawsNumber)
    while gameover==False:
        print("Ejima atlieka ",player2,". Objektu liko: ",removingStrawsComputer())
        checkWinner(player1)
        if gameover==True:
            break
        humanLegalMove()        
        print("Objektu liko: ",removingStrawsHuman())
        checkWinner(player2)

def playAgain():
    answer=raw_input("Ar norite zaisti dar karta?(y/n)")
    resetGameover()
    while answer=="y":
        game()
        answer=raw_input("Ar norite zaisti dar karta?(y/n)")
    else:
        print("Aciu uz zaidima!")

game()
playAgain()
```

Comment: Are you sure the indentation is depicted correctly here? Currently, the `if strawsNumber==2:` block can never be executed.

Comment: Also, your entire approach to the problem is rather cryptic. Declaring a variable as `global` and then `return`ing it looks strange - why not pass it right away? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: As a style thing, avoid global variables; you should pass `strawsNumber` as a parameter to the function. However, I don't see any way for `removedNumber` to be 3 if `strawsNumber` is 3 on entry.

Comment: removedNumber  = 3 not ==3.

Comment: If ```strawsNumber``` is 3 what do you expect the function to return?

Comment: What's going on here? `removedNumber==1`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker edited my post to show what I am trying to achieve..

Comment: @BurhanKhalid if it is only 2 straws left, the only option for computer is to select 1. This is what I tried to do..

Comment: `==` means "is equal to" and `=` means "assign". You need `=` not `==`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
def removingStrawsComputer():
    removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    global strawsNumber
    if strawsNumber==1 and random.randint(0,1)==1:
         return 0
    strawsNumber-=removedNumber
    if strawsNumber<1:
         strawsNumber=1
    return strawsNumber
```

Comment: thanks for your help. it seems to work now, but then only one straw left, computer doesn't select anything.. any ideas how to fix this bug?